# how do I block a URL using htacess

Tags: .htaccess

I have people from all over the world hitting my site (example.com) with this URL:  seocheckupx.net/try.php?u=http://example.com.  How do I use htaccess to stop them accessing my site?
I've tried 

Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all

but it did not work.

Comment: I added some code and now instead of the above URL, I am now getting people hitting my site from this URL   example.com.seocheckupx.net/try.php?u=http://example.com
The code I added was from ".htaccess how to block specific url"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=[^&]*
RewriteRule ^try.php$ - [R=404,L]
```

This redirects all requests for `try.php`, with query string `u={any_characters}` to get a 404 response.